# Hide images in ext:ImageCommandColumn based on contents of row

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have a **ImageCommandColumn** inside a **ext Grid**. **ImageCommandColumn** has a attribute named **DataIndex**

Based on its value I wan to show or hide the **Icon** of the **ext:ImageCommand**

if the value is empty then the **Icon="None"** otherwise **Icon="Picture"**

```
 <ext:ImageCommandColumn ColumnID="imgActivityPatient" Width="70px" DataIndex="ACTIVITY_PATIENT_IMAGEID" Header="Picture" Align="Center" Css="padding-left:30px;">
                    <Commands>
                        <ext:ImageCommand CommandName="View" Icon="Picture">
                            <ToolTip Text="Show Picture" />
                        </ext:ImageCommand>
                    </Commands>
                </ext:ImageCommandColumn>
```

I cant find a way to do this. please anyone here would help me?

N:B: the **DataIndex** value can be retrieved by **record.data.ACTIVITY_PATIENT_IMAGEID**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen PrepareCommand event and hide the command in the handler.

Take a look at the following example and the prepareCommand function: http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Commands/Prepare_Commands/